# Cannot open output file first.exe: Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

when i try to run my code in VScode i keep getting error[image: Like in this image]

i saved my file before running every time but i still getting error.
i tried solutions to regarding this post but nothing worked so i uploaded my problem.

Comment: Looks like your code is trying to rename a file that does not exist. Since it's emitting an error with pathnames relative to the current working directory, I would say you're saving the png to some other folder than the code's cwd.

Comment: Please refrain from posting images of code or error messages. Copy and paste those as text, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all your .exe file and 0 file created by code run extension